# Filtered cross-tab query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql table as below.

[image]

I want to run a query on the table to get all the user data in crosstab/pivot format for the users with field_1=Winter.

I know how to make a crosstab query without any filter:

```
SELECT `user_id`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `field_id` = 'field_2' THEN `field_value` ELSE NULL END) AS field_2,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `field_id` = 'field_3' THEN `field_value` ELSE NULL END) AS field_3
FROM `my_table`  
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

[image]

But the above query results in all the users whereas I want to filter out user_2 for whom field_1 = 'Summer'.

I can do that running a PHP for loop on the above result set, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do that using MySql query only, without using a PHP for loop.

I have around 10 distinct values of field_id and thousands of rows of data, so efficiency is a major concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a `having` clause to assert that you want only those user_id which have atleast one row with Summer for field 1.

```
SELECT `user_id`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `field_id` = 'field_2' THEN `field_value` ELSE NULL END) AS field_2,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `field_id` = 'field_3' THEN `field_value` ELSE NULL END) AS field_3
FROM `my_table`  
GROUP BY `user_id`
having sum(field_id = 'field_1' and field_value = 'Summer') > 0;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot (will accept the answer in 4 minutes, when it'll allow me). A side query, do you think this will be faster compared to a PHP for loop (to build such an array) on the basic mysql query result when the number of rows is thousands?

Comment: I'd say yes. The aggregation operation should be faster at DB level. but if this data is not real time, then you can process it in batch and prepare the aggregated result in advance and directly fetch and display.